# Parse error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\connection.inc.php on line 3

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I'm getting an error as i'm trying to create a login page which will allow users to be directed to the right page. help...

```
<?php
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or  die("Cant connect :" . mysql_error());
 
mysql_select_db("test-login",$dbc);
 
or

die("Cant connect :" . mysql_error()); 
 
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is depreciated. Please look into using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: remove semicolon `;` at the end of - `mysql_select_db("test-login",$dbc)`

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon after mysql_select_db() ends that statement. It's like the period at the end of a sentence. But unlike a human language, PHP doesn't let you start a sentence with "or". If you remove the semicolon, it becomes:

```
mysql_select_db("test-login",$dbc)

or

die("Cant connect :" . mysql_error());
```

which is valid PHP.